# PyBingSearch Module: Bing API error

Tags: python, bing, bing-api

I am trying to use the PyBingSearch module from https://github.com/tristantao/py-bing-search to use the Bing API to return search results. In the github page they have an example of how to use it that goes.

```
from py_bing_search import PyBingWebSearch
search_term = "Python Software Foundation"
bing_web = PyBingWebSearch('Your-Api-Key-Here', search_term, web_only=False) # web_only is optional, but should be true to use your web only quota instead of your all purpose quota
first_fifty_result= bing_web.search(limit=50, format='json') #1-50
```

When I try and run the line that declares `first_fifity_result` I get an error stating `Request returned with code 401, error msg: The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported`

Why do I get this error? In my code I made sure to change `Your-Api-Key-Here` to my API key.

Answer (score 0):

Did you swap your API key?  Where is says "Your-API-Key-Here"

```
bing_web = PyBingWebSearch('Your-Api-Key-Here', search_term, web_only=False) # web_only is optional, but should be true to use your web only quota instead of your all purpose quota
```